# "Cannot access a disposed object" in catch block

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I'm writing a windows service. I have a timer method (`private void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)`) which calls business logic and eventually gets to this method:

```
public ServiceHelperResponse CallService(HttpMethod httpMethod, string uri, HttpContent content, string expectedResultcontent)
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> response;
            switch (httpMethod)
            {
                case HttpMethod.Get:
                    response = client.GetAsync(uri);
                    break;
                case HttpMethod.Post:
                    response = client.PostAsync(uri, content);
                    break;
                default:
                    return ServiceHelperResponse.UnhandledError;
            }

            if (response.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var responseContent = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                if (!responseContent.Equals(expectedResultcontent))
                {
                    return ServiceHelperResponse.ExpectedResultNotMatching;
                }
                return ServiceHelperResponse.Ok;
            }

            if (response.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
            {
                return ServiceHelperResponse.Ok;
            }

            return ServiceHelperResponse.WrongResponsecode;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ServiceMonitor.EventLogger.WriteEntry(
            string.Format("Exception while tyring to send http request.\r\n\r\nUri: {0}\r\nContent:\r\n{1}\r\n\r\n{2}",
                uri, content.ReadAsStringAsync(), ex.Message
            ),
            EventLogEntryType.Error
        );
        return ServiceHelperResponse.UnhandledError;
    }
}
```

As you can see the http content is passed in as a parameter. The problem is when an exception occurs because `content` is disposed ("Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Http.StringContent'.")

I found some posts which suggested to use "using" block so I've wrapped entire method (effectively my try...catch block) in `using(content)` however that doesn't solve the problem. What does work however is adding a reference to content at the very beginning of the method (before try) - `var contentForException = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` and then using `contentForException` in the catch block instead of `content`.

What I'd like to understand is why does it behave this way (i.e. *why* is `content` *disposed* before 'catch' block even though it is needed there). Especially why does it ignore "using" block when wrapping the content of the method in it.

---

In case it matters, this is how I call this method from my business logic:

```
var uri = ServiceMonitor.Config.Services.BankDetailsValidationService.Uri;

var content = new StringContent(
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new
    {
        sortCode = "...",
        accountNumber = "..."
    }
), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var expectedResultcontent = "...";

return _restfulServiceHelper.CallService(HttpMethod.Post, uri, content, expectedResultcontent);
```

Comment: The `using` block doesn't _prevent_ objects from being disposed - it _ensures_ objects are being disposed.

Comment: It might help if you tell us which error happened at what line. Something is disposing your content. Looks like PostAsync is overzealous.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Error happens in the "catch" block when trying to WriteEntry - the only one place in the block where I'm using `content`.
A bit more explanation (about PostAsync) would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is it hitting the catch-block?  I meant the original error.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It's hitting catch on this line: `if (response.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)`. That's aggregate exception, but the inner-most exception is System.Net.Sockets.SocketException - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it <IP_address> (because the  service I'm trying to check is not running)

Answer (score 2):

A using block will just force a dispose at the end of the using block, it doesn't prevent a dispose half way through. Once you've accessed the body of the response at the top of the method it doesn't matter if `content` is disposed because you've already retrieved the body of the response and stored it in `contentForException`

Comment: Ok, That helps. Any clue why is my `content` disposed before "catch" block when I'm not using "contentForException"?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's disposed but to find out, you could try debugging it or reading through the framework code. To debug BCL, have a look here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sburke/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code/ To read through the code search for "class HttpContent github" and you'll see a corefx result. That's the source for the core BCL assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen with the HttpContent class, it appears that it disposes of StringContent Objects upon use in a post method. I would imagine that that is what is happening here as well.

Comment: That is the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot. In a foreach loop, I have to create the StringContent each time.